# Firefox keyboard shortcuts don't work when a form field is focused

Tags: linux, firefox, symbolic-link, hotkeys

When using Firefox in Linpus Linux (on an Acer One netbook) some hot keys don't work.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>w</kbd>
<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd>

However

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>

Does still work.

Edit: The version installed is 3.6.

Comment: Maybe Ctrl + w and Alt + d are bound to any text editing features.

Comment: @Michael, maybe! How would I go about 1) finding out 2) removing the binding?

Comment: You could take look at the Firefox documentation or write an email to their support, I'm sorry for not having a better answer, but I don't know if the key bindings in Firefox textboxes are custom or match to any standard.
Also, you may try what happens if you push the hotkeys while some words are marked or stuff like that.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what version of Firefox you have, but perhaps the [Customizable Shortcuts add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/customizable-shortcuts/) can help you discover the shortcuts that are enabled and change them if desired. You may want to consult the documentation on [Keyboard shortcuts](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Keyboard%20shortcuts) as well.

If that still doesn't help, is it possible you have another program running that is intercepting the hot-keys? Try disabling any browser add-ons or applications/system services that could be defining global hot-keys (Skype, Trillian, and display utilities are examples of possible culprits).